# Nativescript Angular Google maps - Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: angular, google-maps, nativescript

Error trying to load google maps with error of "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined" in nativescript using the normal nativescript-google-maps-sdk, and the code is based off the examples that are provided from the main page

Ignore this paragraph, its just here for stackoverflow to accept the question with more text

Here is the stack error

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: push.../node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-    view.js.MapView._createCameraPosition(file:///node_modules\nativescript-google-maps-sdk\map-    view.js:239:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js.MapView.createNativeView(file:///node_modules\nativescript-google-maps-sdk\map-view.js:68:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase._setupUI(file:///node_modules\@nativescript\core\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:492:0)
System.err:     at (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\core\ui\core\view-base\view-base.js:534:0)
```

Component Html

```
<GridLayout>
 <MapView (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"></MapView>
</GridLayout>
```

Component Ts

```
import { Component, OnInit , ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { MapView, Marker, Position } from "nativescript-google-maps-sdk";


registerElement("MapView", () => require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk").MapView);


@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


    @ViewChild("MapView", {static: true}) mapView: ElementRef;


    latitude =  -33.86;
    longitude = 151.20;
    zoom = 8;
    minZoom = 0;
    maxZoom = 22;
    bearing = 0;
    tilt = 0;
    padding = [40, 40, 40, 40];
    // mapView: MapView;


    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Init your component properties here.
    }

    lastCamera: string;

    constructor() {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    //Map events
    onMapReady(event) {
        console.log('Map Ready');

        this.mapView = event.object;

        console.log("Setting a marker...");

        var marker = new Marker();
        marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(-33.86, 151.20);
        marker.title = "Sydney";
        marker.snippet = "Australia";
        marker.userData = {index: 1};
        this.mapView.addMarker(marker);
    }

}
```

dependencies

```
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.0",
    "nativescript-angular-cli": "^0.1.9",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.3.0",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "2.8.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

Comment: Why have you installed `nativescript-google-maps-sdk` plugin as dev dependency, it suppose to be a dependency. Try a clean build once plugin is installed.